# Compiled form of named union fields in v3.1

Tags: f#, discriminated-union, f#-3.1

Firstly, is the F# 3.1 spec available online? If so, the answer for this should be easy enough to find.

I'm wondering if the compiled form of discriminated unions with [named fields](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2013/06/27/announcing-a-pre-release-of-f-3-1-and-the-visual-f-tools-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) (added in 3.1) will include properties with the names of the fields, instead of the usual `Item1`, `Item2`, ... properties.

Comment: I don't think the spec is available yet.  Decompiling is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the specification is not available yet, so the only way to tell is to try it.
I installed VS 2013 RC, so I thought I could check using this union:

```
type Expression = 
  | Add of Left:Expression * Right:Expression
  | Constant of number:int
```

As expected, it does generate named properties, which are nicely useable from C#:

[image]

In fact, it also uses the name in parameters of the construction functions:

[image]

If you're using them for C# interoperability, then you'll probably want to write the union member names in `PascalCase`, because the compiler does not automatically capitalize the name of the property if you use lowercase name (but interestingly, it does use a lowercase name for the parameters).